# Fetching owner of a polymorphic relationship in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, laravel-5.4

So, I'm having trouble fetching the owner of a polymorphic relationship. It is fairly simple. Followed exactly as the documentation says. I've been able to fetch the child but not the owner.

This is my tables structure:

[image: histories table structure]

Table structure for inventories table:

[image: Structure for inventory table]

History model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
  'inventory' => 'App\Inventory',
  'customer' => 'App\Customer',
  'supplier' => 'App\Supplier',
]);

class History extends Model
{
  public function product()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
  }

  public function moveTo()
  {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}
```

And this is the Inventory model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
  public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
  }

  public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
  }

  public function histories()
  {
    return $this->morphMany('App\History', 'moveTo');
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, `dd($history->moveTo);` returning the value of `null`.

But if I do `dd($inventory->histories);`, all the data is there.

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include it inside relation `$this->morphTo('moveTo');` as well

```
public function moveTo()
{
  return $this->morphTo('moveTo');
}
```

I'm not sure but Laravel Morph Relationship use `able` as postfix e.g. `commentable`, `taggable`. Such that you don't have to do above.

This solved my problem. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Does this answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the morphMap on your Inventory model but it needs to be defined in a **service provider**. You can build your own service provider or put it in the boot method of the `AppServiceProvider`.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Relation::morphMap([
            'inventory' => 'App\Inventory',
            'customer' => 'App\Customer',
            'supplier' => 'App\Supplier',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Still returning `null`.

Comment: But It's still good practice to do it by using `ServiceProvider` even though it doesn't fix :)